# .NET webclient request code to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, converters

I have some .NET-code that I need to convert into Javascript/jQuery.

I presume it could be done with AJAX, but I have no clue how to do it. Can anyone here help me with this?

```
public  string  SendSMS(string  to,  string  from,  string  message) {
    WebClient  wc =  new  WebClient();            
    var  encoding =  Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");            
    var  url =  new  StringBuilder();            
    url.Append("https://cpa.eurobate.com/push2.php?");            
    url.Append("&bruker="  +  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_user, encoding));            
    url.Append("&passord="  +  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_pass, encoding));            
    url.Append("&avsender="  +  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(from, encoding));            
    url.Append("&til="  +  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(to, encoding));            
    url.Append("&melding="  +  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message, encoding));            
    wc.Encoding = encoding;            
    return  wc.DownloadString(url.ToString());
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can keep the code as it is though invoke it using ajax call by passing the required parameters

Comment: @GirishSakhare How exactly would I do that? I cant run .NET-code on my server.

Comment: What alternative of system.web.WebClient are you thinking to use? if not running .NET?

Comment: Thats the million dollar question @GirishSakhare! ...and why I need a javascript equivalent of the code example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery you can use this code:

```
$.get( "test.cgi", { bruker: "xxx", passord: "xxx", avsender: "xxx", til: "xxx", melding: "xxx" } )
.done(function( data ) {
 alert( "Response: " + data );
});
```

You don't specify encoding and you don't url encode query string parameters.